# Meaning of the term "Sledgehammer"

Tags: terminology

I know a Sledgehammer is a special type of hammer, but I still do not quite get the exact meaning of the word in such a paragraphs as:

> The computational sledgehammer par excellence is the spectral sequence; these are essential in the Cartan-Eilenberg and Tohoku approaches where they are needed, for instance, to compute the derived functors of a composition of two functors. Spectral sequences are less essential in the derived category approach, but still play a role whenever concrete computations are necessary.

Does it mean something like the key to decipher a problem, to facilitate or easy up computation, or does it mean something like the nemesis in this context, a fatal flaw which makes everything crash?

Comment: It means that the technique is a great computational tool- a heavy tool for smashing many problems. "Hulk Smash"

Comment: It means that one is using a a very powerful tool where a much lower-powered tool would suffice to do the job, like using a sledgehammer to pound a nail when a carpenter hammer would suffice, or using a nuclear bomb to kill a mosquito, etc.

Comment: @Bill: In this context I think that voldemort is right: it’s simply a very powerful computational tool. Using it is sometimes necessary and sometimes overkill.

Comment: @Brian Right, but one wouldn't call it a sledgehammer in specific cases where there is no simpler way. An analogous remark might be made about the use of the Euclidean algorithm, Grobner bases, etc.

Comment: @Bill: But the quoted passage *does* call it a sledgehammer in cases in which it is essential.

Answer (score 0):

A sledgehammer is not just a special hammer, but a very large and heavy hammer.  Normally one uses it for demolition, to break big things.  You wouldn't want to use it to drive a nail, much less a small nail.

Comment: Well, but is it to be taken in the paragraph above as a key allowing some computation, or, on the contrary, as something smashing it and making it impossible?

Comment: Smashing in this case means smashing the problem, the difficulties.  For example, one can sum the harmonic series by a simple formula, or use the sledgehammer of approximating with an integral, then calculating the accuracy of that the approximation.

Comment: Ok,so it is a problem-solving device, so to speak....